# Laravel Blade: passing a variable to a child view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two views

*index* and *content*

The *index* the view that is returned to via a controller

```
return view();
```

In the *index* view I was able to echo out a a variable I passed it.

When cleaning the file I tried creating a second view *content* and including that view in from within the *index*

```
yield('content')
```

How can I pass a variable to *content*?

Answer (score 6):

Try `@include('content')` instead.

This will include the file and all variables already available will automatically be made available in that view.

Answer (score 5):

If `$variable` is defined in your `index` view, and your `content` view extends `index`, you can do this in your `content` view:

```
@extends('index', ['variable' => $variable] )
```